How to recreate a lava eruption from 3ds Max in blender with particle systems
I'm trying to figure out how to recreate this max lava sim in blender: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g_gGj3-HbgM&list=PLF3yi1mU9hNhP1AXA3QHYWtYeFrCNXhia&index=6
I've never used 3DS Max before so idk what the process is there but if you watch the intro per frame I notice the particles are being ejected from a B&W shape/texture  which is changing location every frame and that is somehow projecting the exact shape of the particles with enough initial velocity to eject it into the air and collide with neighbouring particles as they spawn.I know the basics of particle systems but I have no clue on how to work with possible texture projection (if its even possible).



